# Overleaf does not produce pdf for unknown reason

Tags: overleaf, apa7

I have copied and pasted the following code from a previous overleaf project to create an APA style document. It worked just fine before, but now it does not compile. Any help would be appreciated...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,natbib]{apa7}

%\clubpenalty = 10000
%\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{Thesis}

\author{Nicolas}
\affiliation{University x}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} % Start roman numbering
\shorttitle{ }
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Start page numbering

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: show the complete log-file of this example.

Comment: Both the raw logs and the output.log files are at least 1000 lines long.. Is it that what you are asking for?

Comment: yes, you naturally can try to shorten them by removing some unrelated packages from your example. Simply comment a package and check if the error is still there.

Comment: @Nicolas Don't use `utf8x`

Comment: Commenting out utf8x did the trick. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just for future reference: If (La)TeX issues an error, this error will be among the last things that are written to the log. Try to find the *first* error that you can find in the log. Adding this to your question on this site here will help understanding the problem.

Comment: nevertheless look into the log-file to learn about the error message so that next time you can show it and also search for it. That perhaps would have lead to https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/248